# Doubt in JK Flip flop simplification of boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic

I have following doubt in digital. Please have a look.

From characteristic table of JK flipflop,  I made sop expression . Then I made kmap. Both are giving different answers. Kindly have a look ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: The (J)(~K) term in your boolean algebra is an extra redundancy.  There should be some boolean algebra you can do to simplify it out.

Comment: Any clue sir...........

Comment: Consensus Law...